# Smack 4.1.3 org.jivesoftware.smack.chat package not found

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, smack, asmack

Following is our progress-

1. Installed openfire server on Amazon Ubuntu instance.
2. Developing Android client app using smack 4.1.3 lib.
3. We have developed Registration and Login module till now.

Issue we are facing-
Now that we are trying to develop chat module following package is failing to import- "org.jivesoftware.smack.chat".
However documentation mentions that such package exist. He expanded jar file to find that no such package exist.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274020/integrating-smack-with-android-studio-project-for-chat-application), the question in the link is quite self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Adding the smack-im maven dependency to my pom.xml fixed the problem.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.igniterealtime.smack/smack-im/4.1.7

Edit: Here is the dependency I used for version 4.1.7:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smack-im</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12339111)

Comment: @camden_kid Thanks, I'm still new to commenting/answering on stackoverflow. I will edit my answer to include the important part.